# A RenderConstrainedBox expected a child of type RenderBox but received a child of type RenderSliverPadding

Tags: flutter

Now I am using SliverPadding like this:

```
SizedBox(
                  height: 200.0,
                  child: SliverPadding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
                    sliver: viewService.buildComponent("articlelist"),
                  ))
```

but it shows error that:

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following assertion was thrown building Container(bg: Color(0xffffffff), constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=Infinity, 738.5<=h<=Infinity)):
A RenderConstrainedBox expected a child of type RenderBox but received a child of type RenderSliverPadding.

RenderObjects expect specific types of children because they coordinate with their children during layout and paint. For example, a RenderSliver cannot be the child of a RenderBox because a RenderSliver does not understand the RenderBox layout protocol.
The RenderConstrainedBox that expected a RenderBox child was created by: SizedBox ← Column ← Padding ← ColoredBox ← ConstrainedBox ← Container ← _PointerListener ← Listener ← _GestureSemantics ← RawGestureDetector ← GestureDetector ← ComponentWidget<ChannelDetailState>-[<ChannelDetailComponent>] ← ⋯
The RenderSliverPadding that did not match the expected child type was created by: SliverPadding ← SizedBox ← Column ← Padding ← ColoredBox ← ConstrainedBox ← Container ← _PointerListener ← Listener ← _GestureSemantics ← RawGestureDetector ← GestureDetector ← ⋯
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Container file:///Users/dolphin/Documents/GitHub/cruise-open/lib/src/page/channel/channeldetail_component/view.dart:81:14
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      RenderObjectWithChildMixin.debugValidateChild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2977:9)
#1      RenderObjectWithChildMixin.debugValidateChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:3004:6)
#2      SingleChildRenderObjectElement.insertRenderObjectChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6132:25)
#3      RenderObjectElement.attachRenderObject (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5805:35)
#4      RenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5501:5)
...
====================================================================================================
Reloaded 13 of 1516 libraries in 1,527ms.
```

how to make `RenderConstrainedBox` could contain `RenderSliverPadding`? what should I do to fix it? This is the articlelist page:

```
return SliverList(
    delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context, index) {
      return Slidable(
        key: Key(state.articles[index].id.toString()),
        closeOnScroll: true,
        actionPane: SlidableScrollActionPane(),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconSlideAction(
            color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
            icon: Feather.arrow_up_circle,
            //onTap: () => handleUpvote(context, item: item),
          ),
        ],
        dismissal: SlidableDismissal(
          closeOnCanceled: true,
          dismissThresholds: {
            SlideActionType.primary: 0.2,
            SlideActionType.secondary: 0.2,
          },
          child: SlidableDrawerDismissal(),
          onWillDismiss: (actionType) {
            //handleUpvote(context, item: item);
            return false;
          },
        ),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
          child: OpenContainer(
            tappable: true,
            closedElevation: 0,
            closedColor: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
            openColor: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
            transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
            closedBuilder: (BuildContext c, VoidCallback action) =>
                getViewType(currentView, state.articles[index]),
            openBuilder: (BuildContext c, VoidCallback action) =>
                buildArticle(state.articles[index]),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }, childCount: state.articles.length),
  );
```

Comment: Try wrapping you `SliverPadding` with `SliverToBoxAdapter`.

Comment: What is `viewService.buildComponent()`?

Comment: I have tried this way but it seems not work.@گوروسینی

Comment: I have pasted the component code of articlelist @PreetShah

Answer (score 1):

RenderBox and RenderSliver are different layout protocols for Rendering. You can watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=996ZgFRENMs) to learn more about this.

The issue here is that a Sliver is being used as a child in SizedBox - which is a RenderBox. This isn't allowed since `SizedBox` is a RenderBox and expects a 'RenderBox' widget, not RenderSliver. If you need to set Slivers inside a RenderBox, you can wrap the Sliver first in [CustomScrollView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomScrollView-class.html).